# How to allow users to check a checkbox to make a view their default view

Tags: views

Situation:

A view with nodes, which has views displays 'Thumbnail list' and 'Compact list'.

The users can select one of the display types in a menu, that has both options under 'Articles' parent menu item.

Parent 1, 2 and 3 are views.

How can I allow users to set their personal default view display (thumbnails or compact) for each Parent? With other words: 
There should be a checkbox on the thumbnail list and compact list pages, that says "use this as my default list view for this parent"

[image]

Comment: You want to do this for logged in users?

Comment: Yes, for authenticated users.